# Could not commit JPA transaction while working with post request

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security

I'm attempting to send a post request with an image attachment and employee details in json format. For ImageData and Employee, I have distinct tables. I am able to store image data with my code, but not employee data.The error message "Could not commit JPA transaction" is displayed.
Here I am sharing my code details

```
#Post Request
@PostMapping("/create")
    public Employee tempCreateEmployee(
            @RequestParam("json") String json,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
    ) throws CustomException {
        try {

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            logger.info("data received as string");

            Employee employee = objectMapper.readValue(json, Employee.class);
            logger.info(employee.toString());

            logger.info("Received employee data: {}", employee);
            
            int imageId=fileService.uploadImageFile(file);
            logger.info("file processing successful");
            
            employee.setImageid(imageId);
            logger.info(employee.toString());
           
            return employeeService.save(employee);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           
            throw new CustomException("Employee object not created");
        }
    }
```

Service method for uploading image

```
public int uploadImageFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        ImageData imageData= filesRepo.save(ImageData.builder()
                .name(file.getOriginalFilename())
                .type(file.getContentType())
                .id(filesRepo.findAll().size()+1)
                .image_filedata(ImageUtils.compressImage(file.getBytes())).build());
        
       
        return imageData.getId();

    }
```

**Employee Model class:**

```
package com.SpringTask.SpringTask.Models;

import com.SpringTask.SpringTask.Encryption.Encrypt;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.*;
import jdk.jfr.DataAmount;


import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;


import lombok.*;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Setter
@Getter
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="tableEmployees")

public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer id;


    public String firstName;

  
    public String lastName;

    
    public String address;

    
    public String email;


    
    public int phoneNumber;

  

    private int imageid;

   }
```

**ImageData model class:**

```
package com.SpringTask.SpringTask.Models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade;

import java.util.Arrays;


@Entity
@Table(name = "tableImageData")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter

public class ImageData {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String type;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image_filedata", columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    private byte[] image_filedata;
    
}
```

[image]

I've tried debugging , but every time same issue appears. I have verified my database setup and code logic.
Could not commit JPA transaction means?

Comment: please add a log or any trace for the exception or error.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0fVt.png)

When sending a request in your postman, you can try to send your data via raw and json model in Body.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here I am sending post request which includes two model classes. In this case It's better to use form data. I have to send attachment within same request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to share your JSON data and  `EmployeeService` class to understand the issue better.

From the image you shared, I found out one issue:

You give `id` for creating an employee but in the `Employee` model, it is generated by Hibernate automatically in your model by specifying this: `@GeneratedValue`. So it is wrong, you should not add **id** field in your JSON data. That might be the reason for getting the error.

If you want to give `id` externally, then you need to remove `@GeneratedValue` annotation in `Employee` class.

Comment: First I tried to remove @GeneratedValue, it's not working.. However Now i got some idea to do it. will try different way.. thanks for response